# How works loadUserByUsername method of UserDetails ( Mine have empty username)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've configure Spring Security in my application. I want to test I can log in my application, i've let default login url. Here is my spring config file :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
 <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
 </http>

<authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
</authentication-manager>           
</beans:beans>
```

Below my customerUserDetailsServiceImpl code :

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private IUserServices userServices;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userServices.findUserByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            //LOGGER.error("No user found with username: " + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + email);
        }
        //TODO change 
         boolean enabled = true;  
          boolean accountNonExpired = true;  
          boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;  
          boolean accountNonLocked = true;  

          UserDetails userDetails =  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(),enabled,accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,getAuthorities(user.getRole())); 

          Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
          return userDetails;
    }

    public Collection getAuthorities(Role role) {
           // public Collection<!--? extends GrantedAuthority--> getAuthorities(Long role) {  
                List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));  
                return authList;  
            }  




    // TODO AMELIORER
    public List<String> getRoles(Role role) {  

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();  

        if (role.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {  
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");  
            roles.add("ROLE_USER");

        } 
        else if(role.equals("ROLE_USER")){
            roles.add("ROLE_USER");
        }
        return roles;  
    }  

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {  
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();  

        for (String role : roles) {  
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));  
        }  
        return authorities;  
    }  

      }
```

I make post request on the url

In the result i have a 200 http code and after debuging i notice that on line

```
User user = userServices.findUserByEmail(email);
```

Of my custom user details service the email is empty. Why this ? How username and password is provide to userdetails ?
[image]
Thanks for helping

Comment: It seems this is the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270421/passing-password-through-spring-security-to-dao-object may be useful

Comment: Thanks i've just read your answer but it s not the same problem

Comment: Don't set the context in your service!!! Only retrieve the user and let Springhandle the rest. It cannot be null as you are always assigning it -> `email = "dkiala@gmail.com";` (Reassigning method arguments is bad practice imho).

Comment: Add full source code of all project files. I'll run it for simulate your issue.

Comment: M.Deinum  i added the email to test is i was able to fetch user details. So my username is still null

Comment: I started the project with your spring config and simple CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl which simply displays username and return null, and its works great except that it is necessary to replace the pattern = "/user/*" on the pattern = "/user/**" and the prevention of unnecessary line <http pattern = "/resources/**" security = "none" />. Show code index file and web.xml

Comment: @0x5a4d it's work great !!! What is the difference between the both pattern "/user/*" and "/user/**". Write an answer so i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between / ** and / * well explained in the class description [org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html), there are good examples, look